# Is there a way to get a JQuery variable content with JAVA SE?

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, html

Is there a way to get the content of `$(this).tree('toJson')` with JAVA SE?
Recently I saw a JAVA SE code getting a website's content using an `URL`, and it makes me wonder if it is possible to get an specific content from JS/JQuery.

Thanks in advance.

**This is what I saw using JAVA SE:**

```
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;

public class URLReader {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        URL oracle = new URL("http://www.oracle.com/");
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
        new InputStreamReader(oracle.openStream()));

        String inputLine;
        while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null)
        System.out.println(inputLine);
        in.close();
    }
}
```

**This is my 'APP':**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  //var data is a dynamic JSON file that should be created in the backend.
  var data = [{
    label: 'node1',
    id: 1,
    children: [{
      label: 'child1',
      id: 2
    }, {
      label: 'child2',
      id: 3
    }]
  }, {
    label: 'node2',
    id: 4,
    children: [{
      label: 'child3',
      id: 5
    }]
  }];
  $('#tree1').tree({
    data: data,
    autoOpen: true,
    dragAndDrop: true
  });


  console.log($('#tree1').tree('toJson')); //This will give you the loading jqtree structure.

  $('#tree1').bind(
    'tree.move',
    function(event) {
      event.preventDefault();
      // do the move first, and _then_ POST back.
      event.move_info.do_move();
      console.log($(this).tree('toJson')); //this will give you the latest tree.
      $.post('http://system.com', {
        tree: $(this).tree('toJson')
      });
      alert("done"); //this will post the json of the latest tree structure.
    }
  );


});
```

Comment: Nothing is impossible, but this would require the Java program to mimic a browser by parsing the DOM tree and using a Javascript engine to be able to operate on it.

Comment: Are you asking how to parse html on the server with java, or whether you can call jquery from a server side java application?

Comment: I think you'll find that the Java code you show is reading the page's source, which is doable because an html page's source is just text. That's not the same as actually running the page's JS and accessing its variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way to get data from the client (where your JQuery runs) to the server (where your JAVA code runs) is by sending it along in a server call. The easiest form would be to send it along in the url on a HTTP GET request or in the body of a HTTP POST request.

EDIT: In that case a servlet (possibly a web framework such as JSP or Apache Wicket) should be running on your server to capture the request.

Also, be sure to think about what information you are sending along, if it's private, does it need to be encrypted, do you need a secure (HTTP**S**) connection, etc.

Keep in mind that certain kinds of data/character might not be sutable for use in a URL or in POST DATA so you might need to encode that data (for example, in base 64) to be able to get/post it.

Comment: The information is not important, I don't think it needs to be encrypted. So what do you recommend?

Comment: So, basically you're saying that I should use `AJAX`?

Comment: Not necessarily Ajax, can also be a plain old HTTP request, but yeah, if you want to send some (user generated?) content from your client webpage to your server you typically use a POST with the data embedded in the post data (possibly through a form).

Comment: and to handle it on server-side it should/could be a servlet?

Comment: Depending on what exactly you want to do with it, yes, it should be a servlet at minimum.

Comment: I've been studying about servlets a lot, I know how to create, but I have problems when setting them up, butIthink I'm gonna try it anyway, thanks for helping me :)

Comment: #Calne nailed it, this is a case for AJAX since you want the contents of `$(this).tree('toJson')` without a page reload. I wrote similar code to live complete typing in a jQuery UI form based on database results.

Comment: If you want to live update *part of your page* then Ajax is indeed the way to go (though it can still be done with full page reloads, you generally don't want that O_O).

This particular problem seems to want to do that so yeah, AJAX is the way to go then, I agree. :-)

In general though, just posting data from the client to the server can (and in some cases should) just as well be done by simple plain old HTTP(S) requests (ie, non-Ajax). For those coming after.